# CentOS 7, 2 NICs, 2IPs

Tags: centos, networking, routing

The CentOS 7 server has 2 nics (eth0 & eth1) and 2 public static IPs. The Ip of eth1 is unreachable.

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
DEVICE=eth0
GATEWAY=37.32.20.1
HWADDR=fa:16:3e:fe:eb:e6
IPADDR=37.32.23.77
MTU=1500
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
ONBOOT=yes
STARTMODE=auto
TYPE=Ethernet
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=fa:16:3e:d6:4d:a8
IPADDR=94.101.179.215
MTU=1500
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
ONBOOT=yes
STARTMODE=auto
TYPE=Ethernet
```

I've defined routing
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

```
37.32.20.0/22 dev eth0 table table200
default dev eth0 via 37.32.20.1 table table200
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1

```
94.101.176.0/22 dev eth1 table table201
default dev eth1 via 94.101.176.1 table table201
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0

```
from 37.32.23.205 lookup table200
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1

```
from 94.101.177.221 lookup table201
```

and the **ip route** is

```
default via 37.32.20.1 dev eth0
37.32.20.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 37.32.23.77
94.101.176.0/22 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 94.101.179.215
```

Now the **eth1** IP is not reachable from internet.

**UPDATE 1**

output for  `sysctl -ar '\.rp_filter` command:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
```

**UPDATE 2**

output for  `ip neigh` command:

```
94.101.176.1 dev eth1 lladdr aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:cc STALE
37.32.20.1 dev eth0 lladdr aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:cc DELAY
```

Comment: This looks about how multi-homing should be done. So there's probably a tiny little detail somewhere among multiple possible ways. The first detail would be `rp_filter`. Are any results from `sysctl -ar '\.rp_filter'` equal to 1 (rather than 0 or 2)? If yes, more settings are needed.

Comment: the `sysctl -a|grep rp_filter` command output is `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2`. Iwill update my question by the output.

Comment: I meant, please run this: `ip rule add iif eth1 lookup table201` (not table200).

Comment: Thank you, but no chance to work...

Comment: I'd check for firewall rules too. But anyway this is ongoing debugging. Usual tools for this are `tcpdump`, `ip -4 neigh` and `ip route get from a.b.c.d [iif ethX] to e.f.g.h` (with iif ethX only if a.b.c.d isn't belonging to the server). Good luck.

Comment: @A.B, thank you. That was server provider firewall problem. Now everything is Ok.